# Parse colors used in Word document, use as backcolor for ListViewItem - wrong color

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to list all font colors used in a Word document, display them as colored ListViewItems.

I can parse the doc and get all unique font colors.

What does not work? - Getting the ListViewItems in the correct color. Grey35 appears as yellow, green as dark green.

Here are my active code sections for that

```
var maxnum = doc.Words.Count;
var ind = 0;
foreach (Word.Range wd in doc.Content.Words)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wd.Text.Trim('\r', '\n', ' ')))
    {
        ind++;
        bkwParseColors.ReportProgress(100*ind/maxnum, wd.Font.Color);
    }
}
```

And here's what I do with it:

```
private void bkwParseColors_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    var color = (Word.WdColor)e.UserState;
    var drin = lstColors.FindItemWithText(color.GetHashCode().ToString());
    if(drin==null)
    {
        var li = new ListViewItem(color.GetHashCode().ToString());
        li.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle((int) color);
        lstColors.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

Alas, instead of grey, I get yellow, instead of Word's green I get a dark, full green and instead of a light grey I get a dark 50% grey (at least much darker). The only correct color is black.

During debugging I also found that the first grey, which translates to yellow in the ListView is listed as wdWhite. :-??

It almost looks like I am only getting "full colors" with some value (lightness) missing.
Can someone tell me how to get the correct color?

Using Word 2010, VS Community 2013, Framework 4.0.

**Edit:** I seem to be getting closer!

==> The behavior is different depending on whether I have colored the text using "theme colors" that come up directly when clicking text color, or whether I click "More colors" and then pick one from the color wheel! If I color text from the color wheel, I seem to be getting the correct value, including grey. If I use the grey from the default palette that comes up first, grey is denoted as "White, Background 1, darker xx%", which would explain the wdWhite.

Unfortunately, this is meant for docs that already contain colored text and the coloring is not under my control. So I need a way to include "theme colors" into this.

**Edit2:** It looks as though the answer to my question lies here: [Office 2007 [and higher] interop: retrieve RGB-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189590/office-2007-and-higher-interop-retrieve-rgb-color)
Or basically in the page linked there: http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/Colours/2007.php#UIConsiderations

I will work myself through this in the hope to be getting correct color values from theme colors.

Comment: Try: Font.TextColor.RGB

Comment: @CindyMeister No difference there. Won't work for theme colors. And that VBA code I found is a pain to sift through.

Comment: Interesting, for me it picked up both "color wheel" and theme colors... Anyway, glad you found a solution, and it looks good :-)

Comment: @CindyMeister Pick up? Yeah. But correctly? Try using the read value in Word to find text of that color. Does _that_ work with theme colors? If yes: what Word version are you using? Could be interesting once we upgrade to higher Office version.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes, it does work. Word 2010. Here's the relevant line of code (macro recorded). The color value matches what TextColor.RGB returns and running the recorded macro works: .Find.Font.Color = -603923969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a satisfying result now.
What I first did was

1. use the RgbColorRetriever class by pkuderov as linked in the
   accepted answer to this thread: [Office 2007 [and higher] interop: retrieve RGB-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189590/office-2007-and-higher-interop-retrieve-rgb-color)
2. Since the resulting system color was slightly darker than the Word color, I additionally applied a lightening effect as proposed by Pavel Vladov in this thread (second answer, not the accepted one): [C#: Create a lighter/darker color based on a system color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801406/c-create-a-lighter-darker-color-based-on-a-system-color)

**Edit** Alas, this does not seem to work for certain theme grays. However I need it to also work with these.

Therefore: alternative solution using [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124):

```
private void bkwParseColors_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var docItem = (string) e.Argument;
    using (var docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docItem, false))
    {
        var ind = 0;
        var maxnum = docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>().Count();
        foreach (Run rText in docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>())
        {
            if (rText.RunProperties != null)
            {
                if (rText.RunProperties.Color != null)
                {
                    ind++;
                    bkwParseColors.ReportProgress(100*ind/maxnum, rText.RunProperties.Color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Progress change method for creating ListViewItem in correct color and storing Word color value as well as theme color:

```
private void bkwParseColors_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    var color = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Color)e.UserState;
    var thema = "";
    if (color.ThemeColor!=null)
        thema = color.ThemeColor.Value.ToString();

    var farbe = color.Val.Value; //hex RGB
    var drin = lstColors.FindItemWithText(farbe);
    if(drin==null)
    {
        var li = new myListItem
        {
            Design = thema,
            Farbe = farbe,
            Text = farbe,
            BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + farbe)
        };
        lstColors.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

Some additional info: I needed all this because I need to hide/unhide text of a certain color, but that color is never certain, i.e. depends on the whims of the customer and/or the colors already used in the document...

So for completions sake, here is how I hide all text in the document except for text in the selected color:

```
private void bkwEinblenden_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var args = (List<object>) e.Argument;
    var pfad = (string) args[0];
    var color = (myListItem) args[1];
    using (var docx = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pfad, true))
    {
        var ind = 0;
        var maxnum = docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>().Count();
        foreach (Run rText in docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>())
        {
            bkwEinblenden.ReportProgress(100*ind/maxnum);
            var vanish = new Vanish() { Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true) };
            if (rText.RunProperties == null)
            {
                var runProp = new RunProperties {Vanish = vanish};
                rText.RunProperties = runProp;
            }
            else
            {
                if (rText.RunProperties.Vanish == null)
                    rText.RunProperties.Vanish = vanish;
                else
                {
                    rText.RunProperties.Vanish.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true);
                }
            }
            if (rText.RunProperties.Color != null)
            {
                if (rText.RunProperties.Color.Val == color.Farbe)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color.Design))
                    {
                        if (rText.RunProperties.Color.ThemeColor.Value.ToString() == color.Design)
                        {
                            rText.RunProperties.Vanish.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(false);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rText.RunProperties.Vanish.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your ideas so far. I think I'll better try a new approach using Open XML SDK. I'll have easier access to the used theme and use a custom ListViewItem class to store all necessary values. After all I need to do something with the colored items and I keep running into trouble with theme greys as they stubbornly refuse to be found in the doc later on. Grrrr... :)