# How to get the theme color of a Word document in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I want to get the theme color of my document by C#.
I found out the way to know color RGB in powerpoint. But in Word document, I don't know how to get the information I need.

```
ColorScheme colorScheme = this.presentation.Slides.Range(1).ColorScheme;
MessageBox.Show(colorScheme[PpColorSchemeIndex.ppAccent1].RGB.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(colorScheme[PpColorSchemeIndex.ppAccent2].RGB .ToString());
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you so much. Sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: anyone can help me???

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569480/parse-colors-used-in-word-document-use-as-backcolor-for-listviewitem-wrong-co

Comment: Thank you. I think it's usefull